# Who gives response headers where browser requested cached image?

Tags: javascript, http, browser

I have web page with image cl1.png.
When I open page first time - browser request image:
[image]

When I reopen page - browser get image from cache:
[image]

If look on this request, may see block "Response headers":
[image]

It's file from browser cache, but who send response headers?

Comment: Your server. The server did not send the content, but the image was cached with an "ETag" value so the browser has to verify that that hasn't changed.

Comment: @Pointy But in nginx access logs no records where requested cached image. There is record, only when requested non cached image.

Comment: Well good point. I'd never really thought about it; perhaps the browser synthesizes the response headers based on what it knows from when it cached the image.